# How can I use a unique image as modal content with HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: image, triggers, modal-dialog

I would like it if you clicked on one image, another image would pop up as a modal. I would like the modal content to be a separate image from the trigger, but I borrowed this code from W3Schools and it is written for the same image.

I have tried putting a different image file as src in line 4 with modal-content (id=img01). I have tried changing the var img in line 8 to "img01". I have played around with those two lines in different combinations, but no luck.

I tried to make this as concise as possible, but not entirely sure which parts are the issue, so please forgive any extraneous code, and I can give more if you suspect there is something I'm not including.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! :)

HTML

```
<img id="myImg" src="graphic.jpeg" alt="">  
<div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> 
<img class="modal-content" id="img01"> </div>
```

JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")\[0\];
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS

```
img {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#img01 {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal image content is loaded in JS line `modalImg.src = this.src`.
Try `modalImg.src = "sample/url";` instead of that.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even notice this. Truth be told I have only gotten training in html and css, so my understanding of JS and its syntax is purely on an as-needed basis right now. 

When you say "sample/url" do you mean verbatim or with the new file name? If so, what would that look like if the new image is called logo.png?

Comment: @Sarah JavaScript method `.src=""` just changing HTML `src=""` attribute. For "logo.png" it should look like `modalImg.src = "logo.png";`. Here you have example from w3schools: www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Comment: @Sarah No problem! Good luck ;)